# How come not implementing some Methods are allowed in WindowAdapter?

Tags: java

The `WindowAdapter` class of Java is defined as an abstract class and has many abstract Methods, including:

```
windowClosing()
windowClosed()
windowActivated()
```

All of these methods are empty and Java says the class exists as a convenience for those who do not want to create classes implementing `WindowListener`. Because unlike the `WindowListener` Interface, `WindowAdapter` gives us the choice to implement only one of the abstract methods defined in it.

For example if I add the below code to a class that inherits from `Window`, I make the window closeable through the 'x' button on the upper right corner:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
```

However this confuses me. First of all what exactly is happening here? Am I creating an inner class that extends `WindowAdapter`? The `new` keyword is normally used to create an instance, but obviously I am not allowed to instantiate an abstract class. So why the `new` keyword here?

Second, why do I get away with implementing only one of the abstract methods in `WindowAdapter`?
Normally in Java if I define an abstract class:

```
public abstract class UpperClassAb {
    public abstract void test();

    public abstract int boa();

}
```

and then try to use this class, just like I have used the `WindowAdapter`above:

```
UpperClassAb tester = new UpperClassAb() {
            public void test() {
                System.out.println("mor");
            }
        };
```

I get an error, because I am not implementing all the abstract methods but only one of them. How can I get away with implementing just one of the abstract methods in the case of `WindowAdapter`? Is this a single case, and if not can I imitate this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although WindowAdapter is an abstract class, its methods are not abstract but empty. So you do not have to implement them, but you can override them if you want.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html

Regarding the new keyword: this is called an anonymous class. You basically create a new class without a name, and instantiate it at the same time. So the new class does not have a name, it extends WindowAdapter, overrides one method, and can ONLY be instantiated at this location (because it has no name)

Comment: Thanks that explains the second question, how about the first one, why do we use the new keyword when defining an inner class there?

Comment: i edited my answer to include an explanation for the new keyword

Comment: @loonytune It's called an argument defined anonymous inner class or a method local anonymous inner class to be precise.

Comment: although I must say the notation is a bit weird because new WindowAdapter() gives the impression that we are instantiating the WindowAdapter Class

Comment: in a way you are, at least a subclass of WindowAdapter without a name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement WindowListener, you should provide implementation for all the methods. Here window adapter is nothing but the abstract class which provides partial implementations for the window events. Because of this you can provide the implementation for the particular event(e.g windowclose)